# Click em elemento gerado dinamicamente não funciona

Tags: javascript, jquery

Oi, estou clonando um elemento via jQuery e quando clico em um item do elemento clonado o click não funciona, segue códigos de exemplo:

Clonando:

```
var template = $(".products .product.template").clone().prependTo($(".products")).removeClass("template");
```

Click no elemento:

```
$(".remover").click(function(e) {
    console.log("teste");
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
});
```

Essa classe remover tá dentro do template do primeiro exemplo de código (clonando).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem que usar `.clone(true)` como descrito na documentação: https://api.jquery.com/clone/

> **.clone( [withDataAndEvents ] )**
>
> Um *booleano* que indica se os manipuladores de eventos devem ser copiados junto com os elementos. A partir do jQuery 1.4, os dados dos elementos serão copiados também.

Exemplo:

```js
var bar = $('.foo .bar');

bar.click(function () {
    console.log(Date.now());
});

var clonado = bar.clone(true);

clonado.appendTo('.baz');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Copiado .bar de .foo para .baz:</h1>

<div class="foo">
Original: <div class="bar">Click em foo</div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="baz">
Copiado:
</div>
```

---

### Delegando eventos

Outra maneira de chegar ao resultado desejado é delegando eventos, por exemplo você define o `.click` no `document`, mas informa que o objeto esperado ("target") é o `.baz` (exemplo apenas) e então todos elementos que forem adicionados a qualquer momento terão o evento do click, ou seja estará tudo a partir do `document`, exemplo:

```js
var bar = $('.foo .bar');

//O evento click de document será delegado para todos ".bar"
$(document).on('click', '.bar', function () {
    console.log(Date.now());
});

setInterval(function () {
    var clonado = bar.clone();

    clonado.appendTo('.baz');
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Copiado .bar de .foo para .baz:</h1>

<div class="foo">
Original: <div class="bar">Click em foo</div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="baz">
Copiados:
</div>
```